# Replacement of import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration; in Spring Test 4.3.1 version?

Tags: querydsl, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm working on the `JPA QueryDSL` example. In this example I created `PersonDaoTest.java`. Earlier I was using the lower version of `spring-test` as client asked to update it its latest version so I used `4.3.1.RELEASE`. When I used this version I see that `import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;` is @deprecated. Could anyone please let me know whats the replacement of `import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;` in latest version ?

**PersonDaoTest.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class PersonDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    //

    @Test
    public void testCreation() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Erich", "Gamma"));
        final Person person = new Person("Kent", "Beck");
        personDao.save(person);
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson"));

        final Person personFromDb = personDao.findPersonsByFirstnameQueryDSL("Kent").get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals(person.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultipleFilter() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Erich", "Gamma"));
        final Person person = personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Beck"));
        final Person person2 = personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson"));

        final Person personFromDb = personDao.findPersonsByFirstnameAndSurnameQueryDSL("Ralph", "Johnson").get(0);
        Assert.assertNotSame(person.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(person2.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrdering() {
        final Person person = personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Gamma"));
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson"));
        final Person person2 = personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Zivago"));

        final Person personFromDb = personDao.findPersonsByFirstnameInDescendingOrderQueryDSL("Kent").get(0);
        Assert.assertNotSame(person.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(person2.getId(), personFromDb.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxAge() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Gamma", 20));
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson", 35));
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Zivago", 30));

        final int maxAge = personDao.findMaxAge();
        Assert.assertTrue(maxAge == 35);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMaxAgeByName() {
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Gamma", 20));
        personDao.save(new Person("Ralph", "Johnson", 35));
        personDao.save(new Person("Kent", "Zivago", 30));

        final Map<String, Integer> maxAge = personDao.findMaxAgeByName();
        Assert.assertTrue(maxAge.size() == 2);
        Assert.assertSame(35, maxAge.get("Ralph"));
        Assert.assertSame(30, maxAge.get("Kent"));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13472

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Documentation exists for a reason: as a developer you are expected to read it!

The [Javadoc for @TransactionConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html) explicitly states:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> As of Spring Framework 4.2, use `@Rollback` or `@Commit` at the class
>   level and the `transactionManager` qualifier in `@Transactional`.

Thus, the answer to your question is simply `@Rollback`.

But... more importantly, your declaration of `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)` is useless since the default is `true` anyway. So you can just delete that altogether.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks. This would be needs to be change at more that 1000 of test cases of mine. Also at Service level too.

Comment: You can likely achieve with that with a simple search-and-replace in your IDE, text editor, or via perl, sed, awk, etc. from the command line.